# JQuery hide mouse if it's not moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to hide the mouse if it hasn't moved for a period of time.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var j;
    $(document).mousemove(function() {
        clearTimeout(j);
        $('html').css({cursor: 'default'});
        j = setTimeout('hide();', 1000);
    });
});

function hide() {
    $('html').css({cursor: 'none'});
}
```

When the hide() function is called the cursor is hidden, but unhides a split second later. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is a terrible idea to hide user's mouse pointer

Comment: @zerkms I would disagree. Jquery can be used to create fullScreen games too, in that case I don't need the mouse if I read that I can use the keyboard. And if the mouse appears if I move it... I will get the point in a nano-second.

Comment: @zerkms The second they move their mouse it shows it again.

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+hide+cursor. In which browser are you testing? I remember vaguely that there might be a bug in Chrome regarding this.

Comment: @Felix Kling I can hide the cursor, I was wondering why it unhides almost instantly when it's put inside a mousemove event. I just tested it in FireFox and what I'm doing actually works, so you are right, it is a bug with Chrome :( Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think @mVChr found the bug I was talking about. I remember now that hiding the cursor somehow triggered `mousemove` in Chrome. That's the bug report: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=103041

Comment: You might be able to use a custom cursor loaded from a URI that is simply transparent. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3354258/880434

Answer (score 5):

Your initial problem is that the hiding of the mouse triggers `mousemove` and thus immediately resets it back to default.  So you could solve that like this...

```
var justHidden = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var j;
    $(document).mousemove(function() {
        if (!justHidden) {
            justHidden = false;
            console.log('move');
            clearTimeout(j);
            $('html').css({cursor: 'default'});
            j = setTimeout('hide();', 1000);
        }
    });
});

function hide() {
    $('html').css({cursor: 'none'});
    justHidden = true;
}​
```

### ...BUUUUUT...

You face a problem here which at the moment seems unsolvable to me.  That is, a hidden mouse does not trigger `mousemove` ever, so once it's hidden you will not be able to unhide it as far as I can tell.

I'll keep investigating to see if there's a solution I'm missing.

Comment: In Chrome it still just hides and unhides instantly :(

Comment: Nevermind, it does hide but doesn't show up again like you had said.

Comment: @user802519: mVChr has been close (+1 for that). You just have to reset `justHidden` after a while. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/NmKNC/. It seems a timeout of 100ms is not enough, 500 works fine for me though.

Comment: You perhaps also just could change the cursor to a custom one, where the custom cursor is just an transparent PNG

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread when I was looking for solution for this challenge in 2019. Based on answer here and in ['Hiding the mouse cursor when idle using JavaScript'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354239/hiding-the-mouse-cursor-when-idle-using-javascript) I made a slightly different solution:

```js
var DEMO = {
  INI: {
    MOUSE_IDLE: 3000
  },
  hideMouse: function() {
    $("#game").css('cursor', 'none');
    $("#game").on("mousemove", DEMO.waitThenHideMouse);
  },
  waitThenHideMouse: function() {
    $("#game").css('cursor', 'default');
    $("#game").off("mousemove", DEMO.waitThenHideMouse);
    setTimeout(DEMO.hideMouse, DEMO.INI.MOUSE_IDLE);
  },
  showMouse: function() {
    $("#game").off("mousemove", DEMO.waitThenHideMouse);
    $("#game").css('cursor', 'default');
  },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This simple and clear example gives you the option to start hiding mouse (`DEMO.hideMouse()`) and also to turn this off (`DEMO.showMouse()`). It does not create multiple events on same element. This example shows hiding mouse pointer over `#game` div element. Just change this to the div of your choice or `body`.

As of fully updated Chrome and FF in October 2019: it works on both.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 8 years late but I have a solution:

• First of all download an image of a cursor from the internet or copy my svg code:

```
<svg id="cursor" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 95 92" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M84.6925 46.0105L40.25 20.3516C35.25 17.4648 29 21.0733 29 26.8468L29 78.1645C29 84.9879 37.3721 88.2664 42.0056 83.2575L58.1424 65.8134C58.4853 65.4427 58.9324 65.1846 59.4249 65.0729L82.6003 59.8201C89.255 58.3118 90.6017 49.4222 84.6925 46.0105Z" fill="black" stroke="white" stroke-width="5"/></svg>
```

And add it to your html file.

•Of course, if you want to made it in jQuery, you need to add this script above your js file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

•Then add this (in your JavaScript file):

```js
let timedelay = 1;

function delayCheck() {
  if (timedelay == 2) { //Here you can change this value which changes the time it takes the mouse to hide
    $('#cursor').fadeOut();
    timedelay = 1;
  }
  timedelay += 1;
}
$(document).mousemove(function() {
  $('#cursor').fadeIn();
  timedelay = 1;
  clearInterval(_delay);
  _delay = setInterval(delayCheck, 1000);
});
_delay = setInterval(delayCheck, 1000);
```

Now you'll see just a cursor on the top left of the screen that does what you asked but it's not YOUR cursor, to replace the cursor with the svg do the following:

```js
//in the same js file as before
$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    $('#cursor').offset({
        left: e.clientX,
        top: e.clientY
    });
});
```

```css
/* on the css */
html {
cursor: none;
}
```

If it doesn't work, make sure that you put the jquery file ABOVE the file you wrote.
I hope I have helped someone!
You might want to check if this really works, here's the [demo](https://cursor-hide.netlify.app/).
(Sorry if my English was bad, I'm italian).

(Tip) You will notice that there are two identical functions, if you want to merge them just replace them with this:

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  $('#cursor').fadeIn();
  timedelay = 1;
  clearInterval(_delay);
  _delay = setInterval(delayCheck, 1000);
  $('#cursor').offset({
    left: e.clientX,
    top: e.clientY
  });
});
```