# jQuery if mouse not moving

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was planning to create the effect like when watching video (like Youtube), the mouse is not moving for few second the bottom bar and cursor will automatically hidden, if moving mouse again cursor and bar will show automatically. Any suggestion do do that ? Thanks

```js
var countdown;

$(".stage").hover(function() {
  $(".bar").fadeIn();
  clearTimeout(countdown);
});
countdown = setTimeout(function() {
  $(".bar").fadeOut();
}, 5000);

 $(".stage").hover(
  function(e){ $(".bar").fadeIn(); }, // over
  function(e){ $(".bar").fadeOut();

  }  // out
 );
```

```css
.stage{
  height:400px;
  width:auto;
  background:#ccc;
  }
.bar{
  height:20px;
  width:auto;
  background:#000;
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stage">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071356/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-cursor-in-a-webpage-using-css-or-javascript

Comment: @JohnDevelops so far like the example code

Comment: @cetver thanks but mouse hidden is not I want

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, what have you tried regarding the mouse movement part of what you're trying to achieve, anything? I see the hover is in place.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564690/jquery-hide-mouse-if-its-not-moving)

Answer (score 2):

There is a function in jQuery called [.mousemove()](https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) that you can use for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an working example: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnoLkue/. You should use `mousemove`to appear the `.bar` when it's disappear.

```
$(".stage").hover(function() {
  $(".bar").fadeIn();
    fadeOutBar();
}, function(e){
    $(".bar").fadeOut();
});
$('.stage').mousemove(function() {
    $(".bar").fadeIn();
    fadeOutBar();
});
function fadeOutBar() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".bar").fadeOut();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
time = 0;

time = setInterval(function(){
    //hide bar if he counts to 5 sec
    $(".bar").fadeOut();
},5000);

$('#video').mousemove(function(){
    clearInterval(time);
    //show bar
    $(".bar").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: bar is hidden but when i move my mouse bar still not showing up

Comment: use `.show()` and `.hide()` or whatever you want to use to show the bar

Comment: yes I do tried but still not showing up after I move my cursor

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the old hover and re hover element hide first the .bar

```
$('.stage').mousemove(function() {
   $(".bar").hide();
   $(".bar").fadeIn();
});
```